# Use Bootstrap Navbar in joomla template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla, joomla-template

I'm creating template joomla using bootstrap. With navbar top menu I have code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-7" style="none" />
      </ul>


    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

but html show on web is:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <div class="module">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                                            <ul class="nav menu">
<li class="item-435 current active"><a href="/dv/" title="Start here" >Home</a></li><li class="item-468 parent"><a href="#" title="Efficient navigation" >Menu1</a></li><li class="item-1206 parent"><a href="#" >Menu2</a></li><li class="item-1224 parent"><a href="#" >Menu3</a></li><li class="item-1211"><a href="#" >Menu4</a></li><li class="item-t1252"><a href="#" >Menu5</a></li></ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </ul></div>
```

therefore it show menu form block..
How to show module menu in position template?

Comment: hi... anyone help me @@

Answer (score 0):

for defining your position modules in joomla template,you should use jdoc statements.

```
<jdoc:include type="module" name="mainmenu" title="Main Menu" />
```

for more info go to link:
[jdoc statement](https://docs.joomla.org/Jdoc_statements)

for creating style  of your menu(by a framework css like bootstrap)
you should change templates menu,that there is in folder module.

second way you should  use class suffix module joomla,but way template module is  the best way.